# Determine if button can be seen by user

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uibutton

I have an interesting requirement. I have a webview that expands in size when the user swipes up. This works well, but now I am trying to detect if the user has scrolled up to the top, so that I can minimize it again.

I am trying to do this by placing an image behind the webview, if the user scrolls past the top of the webview, the bounce effect takes place and the underlying image becomes visible. I was trying to use the "hidden" property thinking that the image is hidden when under the webview, but visible when the webview has been pulled down. This however, doesnt seem to work properly.

Anyone have any ideas on how to detect if a button/image is visible to the user?

Comment: So what do you actually want to achieve? hide the view behind your webview or detect when the user has scrolled up?

Comment: All I really need to do is call a method if the user has scrolled to the top of the webview. This might be the wrong approach... Any thoughts on this?

Comment: The webview expands when the user scrolls down the page but you want the webview to contract when the user scrolls up?

Comment: yes, but only if the user has scrolled to the very top of the webview.

Comment: Yes sure, have a look at my post that I will write now. Wait a few minutes please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the UIWebView implements UIScrollViewDelegate, it declares conformity to that protocol, you can use the `ScrollViewDidScroll` delegate method.

First make sure that your `UIWebView` is not inside a `UIScrollView`

> Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled.

Instead, you can access the UIScrollView through the UIWebView properties since we now know that UIWebView is based on a UIScrollView. Your view controller can implement the UIScrollViewDelegate.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end
```

Then you have to set the scrollView property inside your webview to the UIScrollViewDelegate like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Set the scrollView property's delegate protocol to self. This is so that this view controller will receive the delegate methods being fired when we interact with the scrollView.
    webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
}
```

We're only interested in one of the ScrollView's delegate method - scrollViewDidScroll. Then you can detect when the scrollView has been scrolled inside your webview and ultimately have a simple mathematics equation that checks if the scrollView has been scrolled to the top:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{   
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0.0){
        NSLog(@"TOP REACHED so do the chicken dance");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for contentOffset of scroll view of Web view if it's Y==0 then it means that user has scrolled up to the top.

```
CGRect visibleRect;
visibleRect.origin = webView.scrollView.contentOffset;
if(visibleRect.origin.y == 0)
{
//t means that user has scrolled up to the top
}
```

Comment: Hey buddy, just to let you know for the future, this will only let the user know whether or not the scrollView is at the top at the point of time this code was executed. What the OP is asking for is for something to happen only when the user has scrolled up. So for that we use the ScrollViewDidScroll delegate method and detect automatically when the user has scrolled up.

Comment: @Pavan ok Sir  i got it.